# Trying to figure out why function(argument) not console-logging as expected

Tags: javascript

```
var interval = window.setInterval(animate, 500);
var i = 5;
function animate() {
    if (i > 1) {
        i--;
        console.log(i);
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
animate();
```

The above javascript has `var i = 5;` and console logs the numbers 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1. [DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lpsternotes/Cnyjh/)

I wanted to put the starting number into the `animate()` function as an argument though, so I added an argument to `animate()`, defined the variable i as solely `var i;`, and put a number into `animate()`:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(animate, 500);
var i;
function animate(i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        i--;
        console.log(i);
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
animate(10);
```

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lpsternotes/Cnyjh/1/)

However, this second attempt only spits out the number 9, and doesn't spit out 10, 9, 8, 7, etc.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ETA: Title should say function(argument), not function(attribute)

Comment: remove the global declaration for i because i is already a function argument

Comment: check my full edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead have the function recursively call itself, and use `setTimeout` with an anonymous function that passes in the current value of `i`.

```
function animate(i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        i -= 1;
        console.log(i);
        setTimeout(function() {
            animate(i);
        }, 500);
    }
}

animate(10);
```

This way, you don't need to manage an interval, and the animation will only be controlled by the `animate()` method. Cleaner IMO.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UNkhK/

If you still want control over the timeout: You could also extend this guy's functionality by making him into an object.

```
function Animation(delay) {
    this.delay = delay || 500;
    this.timeout = null;
}

Animation.prototype.animate = function(i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        i -= 1;
        console.log(i);
        var self = this;
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            self.animate(i);
        }, this.delay);
    }
}

Animation.prototype.stop = function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}

var animation = new Animation(500);
animation.animate(10);

// Testing
setTimeout(function() {
    animation.stop();
    console.log('Animation stopped prematurely!');
}, 2000);
```

Working fiddle / demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5dZyd/

Answer (score 1):

you didnt use the variable `i`, you created a new one, in short, `i` inside the function definition - `animate(i)` creates a new `var i` for the function, and doesn't use the global one try

```
var i = 10;
function animate() {
    if (i > 1) {
    i--;
    console.log(i);
}
/*
    rest of your code here
*/
animate();
```

see [javascript scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

also use `setTimeout` not `setInterval` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/731625/2683447)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/UNkhK/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the link to setTimeout vs. setInterval... I was just wondering about the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments are local variables that shadow global variables. So if you use the same name `i` for the argument, you can't access the global variable that has that name. You need to use different variables.

```
var global_i;
function animate(local_i) {
    if (local_i !== undefined) { // Will be undefined when called from setInterval
        global_i = local_i;
    }
    if (global_i > 1) {
        global_i--;
        console.log(global_i);
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
animate(10);
```

Comment: i think thats a bit over-complicated

Answer (score 1):

You may try this (call the function from within the function itself and pass the variable `i`)

```
var interval;
function animate(i) {
   if (i > 1) {
        i--;
        console.log(i);
        interval = setTimeout(function(){ animate(i) }, 500);
    }
}
animate(10);
```

[**FIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Cnyjh/11/)

Comment: setTimeout and clearInterval doesn't match... Also setTimeout happens only once you dont need to clear interval. setTimeout is a one time activity... its pair is clearTimeout, but not a case here.

Comment: @PSL, It'll call the function till `i > 1`.

Comment: you dont need to call cleartimeout. remove else part and verify for your understanding...

Comment: @PSL, yes, you are right about both (clearInterval and else), thanks.